# How to stack SpinSail on top of GraphDB remote repository

Tags: graphdb, rdf4j

I am using **GraphDB** to store my triples and need to stack **SpinSail** component upon the **GraphDB** to support **Spin Rules** along with all the rest of the features that **GraphDB** supports by default.

So far I have managed to create a **SailRepository** on the remote server supporting **Spin Rules** (more details below) but it seems that it only supports **Spin** and none of the other features that **GraphDB** supports (e.g. reviewing the Graph, adding triples through files, searching etc.)

The configuration file, once the repository is created, looks like below:

```
@prefix ms: <http://www.openrdf.org/config/sail/memory#> .
@prefix rep: <http://www.openrdf.org/config/repository#> .
@prefix sail: <http://www.openrdf.org/config/sail#> .
@prefix sr: <http://www.openrdf.org/config/repository/sail#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

<#Test1> a rep:Repository;
  rep:repositoryID "Test1";
  rep:repositoryImpl [
      rep:repositoryType "openrdf:SailRepository";
      sr:sailImpl [
          sail:delegate [
              sail:sailType "openrdf:MemoryStore";
              ms:persist true
            ];
          sail:sailType "openrdf:SpinSail"
        ]
    ] .
```

Although a normal configuration file (i.e. if someone would create a repository through the workbench)  would look like the one below:

```
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix rep: <http://www.openrdf.org/config/repository#> .
@prefix sail: <http://www.openrdf.org/config/sail#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

<#Test> a rep:Repository;
  rep:repositoryID "Test";
  rep:repositoryImpl [
      rep:repositoryType "graphdb:FreeSailRepository";
      <http://www.openrdf.org/config/repository/sail#sailImpl> [
          <http://www.ontotext.com/trree/owlim#base-URL> "http://example.org/owlim#";
          <http://www.ontotext.com/trree/owlim#check-for-inconsistencies> "false";
          <http://www.ontotext.com/trree/owlim#defaultNS> "";
          <http://www.ontotext.com/trree/owlim#disable-sameAs> "false";
          <http://www.ontotext.com/trree/owlim#enable-context-index> "false";
          <http://www.ontotext.com/trree/owlim#enable-literal-index> "true";
          <http://www.ontotext.com/trree/owlim#enablePredicateList> "true";
          <http://www.ontotext.com/trree/owlim#entity-id-size> "32";
          <http://www.ontotext.com/trree/owlim#entity-index-size> "10000000";
          <http://www.ontotext.com/trree/owlim#imports> "";
          <http://www.ontotext.com/trree/owlim#in-memory-literal-properties> "true";
          <http://www.ontotext.com/trree/owlim#query-limit-results> "0";
          <http://www.ontotext.com/trree/owlim#query-timeout> "0";
          <http://www.ontotext.com/trree/owlim#read-only> "false";
          <http://www.ontotext.com/trree/owlim#repository-type> "file-repository";
          <http://www.ontotext.com/trree/owlim#ruleset> "owl2-rl-optimized";
          <http://www.ontotext.com/trree/owlim#storage-folder> "storage";
          <http://www.ontotext.com/trree/owlim#throw-QueryEvaluationException-on-timeout> "false";
          sail:sailType "graphdb:FreeSail"
        ]
    ];
  rdfs:label "Test" .
```

The following code was used to create the repository.

```
RemoteRepositoryManager manager = new RemoteRepositoryManager("http://localhost:7200");
        manager.init();

        String repositoryId = "Test1";

        // create a configuration for the SAIL stack
        boolean persist = true;

        // create a configuration for the SAIL stack
        SailImplConfig spinSailConfig = new MemoryStoreConfig(persist);

        spinSailConfig = new SpinSailConfig(spinSailConfig);

        RepositoryImplConfig repositoryTypeSpec = new SailRepositoryConfig(spinSailConfig);

        // create a configuration for the repository implementation
        // RepositoryImplConfig repositoryTypeSpec = new SailRepositoryConfig(backendConfig);

        RepositoryConfig repConfig = new RepositoryConfig(repositoryId, repositoryTypeSpec);
        manager.addRepositoryConfig(repConfig);
```

Once I created this repository I was able to insert the following rule into it through the **SPARQL** section (by using **INSERT DATA**):

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX sp: <http://spinrdf.org/sp#>
PREFIX spin: <http://spinrdf.org/spin#>
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/>

INSERT DATA {
ex:Person a rdfs:Class ;
    spin:rule [
        a sp:Construct ;
    sp:text """PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/>
               CONSTRUCT { ?this ex:childOf ?parent . }
               WHERE { ?parent ex:parentOf ?this . }"""
] . }
```

and then similarly add the following statements:

```
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/>

INSERT DATA {
ex:John a ex:Father ;
        ex:parentOf ex:Lucy .
ex:Lucy a ex:Person .
}
```

After that by running the following query:

```
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/>

SELECT ?child WHERE { ?child ex:childOf ?parent }
```

I was able to confirm that the Spin rule was executed successfully.

**So my question is**:

Is there a way to create a remote repository supporting all the features of GraphDB and **then** stack upon it the SpinSail component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the moment GraphDB (version 8.10.0) does not support SpinSail. Such option is under consideration for one of the next GraphDB releases.